# Error in file upload using Jquery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am trying to upload files using jQuery and AJAX. I have used `FormData` object which is supported in HTML5. I am using IE11. Below is my code:

```
<form id="tradeForm" method="post" action="/trade.action?method=addTrade" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Trade Type : <input type="text" id="tradeType" name="tradeType">
    Trade Document : <input type="file" id="attachedFile" name="attachment" size="40">
</form>
```

I've tried using `$.post`:

```js
$("#tradeForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    url = form.attr("action");

    $.post(url, formData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

And also using `$.ajax`

```
$("#tradeForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    url = form.attr("action");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

I get the following errors:

> Argument not optional

When `$.post` method is used

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3

When `$.ajax` method is used. How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Did you try to use serialize() function? var formData = form.serialize()

Comment: @cralfaro OP is sending a file, so serialize() is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormData` constructor expects a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, so you need to amend your `FormData()` definition. Try this:

```
$("#tradeForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData($form[0]); // note [0] here
    url = $form.prop("action");

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I still get the same error. When I log formData,  I see [object FormData] in the console. I am using jquery 2.1.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

to

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
```

As FormData needs a form the DOM element `this` not the jQuery object `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the form variable to this:

```
 var form  = document.getElementById('tradeForm');
 url = $(form).attr("action");
```

set the `contentType: 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';`

Comment: I still get the same error. When I log formData, I see [object FormData] in the console

Comment: do your site have ssl?

Comment: After updating var form = document.getElementById('tradeForm');           I am getting error - Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'

Comment: change `url = form.getAttribute("action");`

Comment: 'attr' error resolved but getting Network Error 0x2ef3. And I have hosted my application on local server.Is SSL required for applications running locally?

Comment: no is not required on local,what server do you use?

Comment: weblogic server and struts 2.0 at server end

Comment: it may be a server side error try a different type of server use the xampp stack for exemple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107137/discussion-between-karthik-and-madalin-ivascu).

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix for the issue. Below are changes done :

1. Pass DOM element to FormData constructor instead of Jquery Object.
   var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("tradeForm"));
2. Remove attribute - enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form in the html.
   Otherwise it will not be possible to read form data at the server end.
3. Use correct server URL(In my case the URL was wrong). The error message - **SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3** was because of wrong URL. It was misleading.